# Xcode 4.0 Crashes when I try "Validate" or "Submit" 1.1 version of my application

Tags: iphone, xcode

Have you ever seen this problem?

When I click on "Validate" in Organizer, I get the following error: "Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data."  and Xcode crashes.

Under details it says:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[ITunesSoftwareApplicationDescription applicationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20162b520
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
 0  0x00007fff81e13796 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
 1  0x00007fff873710f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
 2  0x00007fff81e6d110 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
 3  0x00007fff81de591f ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
 4  0x00007fff81de1a68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
 5  0x0000000102f9f0ac __50-[AAVFetchApplicationListAssistant viewDidInstall]_block_invoke_0427 (in IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer)
 6  0x00007fff81e1facc __NSArrayChunkIterate (in CoreFoundation)
 7  0x00007fff81e2e7fd ____NSArrayGetIndexesPassingTest_block_invoke_1 (in CoreFoundation)
 8  0x00007fff835dd283 _dispatch_apply_serial (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 9  0x00007fff83594434 dispatch_sync_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
10  0x00007fff835dd22b dispatch_apply_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
11  0x00007fff8369358d _dispatch_apply_slow (in libSystem.B.dylib)
12  0x00007fff81df63ab __NSArrayGetIndexesPassingTest (in CoreFoundation)
13  0x0000000102f9ef27 __50-[AAVFetchApplicationListAssistant viewDidInstall]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer)
14  0x00007fff8359b2c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)
15  0x00007fff83579831 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libSystem.B.dylib)
16  0x00007fff83579168 _pthread_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
17  0x00007fff83579005 start_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I cleared the Cashe, restarted my Mac, and still getting the same error.
What should I do?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have seen this. In my case I never figured it out, but I was able to load my ipa file to the store.

Create an archive file (ipa) and then load it with the Application Loader (on my computer it is in Developer->Applications->Utilities)

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and played around with re-installing xcode. the essential thing about re-installing is that you have to check the box "unix development". after i installed these tools too, "validate" no longer crashed...

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and it happened soon after the organizer was unable to see applications that were 'waiting for upload' in itunes connect. I ended up using  the old xcode 3 method with application loader.

You can find a download link in the apple documentation or you probably already have it.